# Python regular expression with unicode

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I use python 2.7 (I cannot use 3.4),

```
text = """
saú$_ß$¤×÷asd县阴őasdCharacters: \"县阴 asdsadsasd县阴
"""
text = unicode(text, "utf-8")
print("Method 1\n")
reg = "Characters: \"[\u4e00-\u9fff]+.*?"  
reg = unicode(reg, "utf-8")
pattern = re.compile(reg, re.UNICODE | re.MULTILINE)
for m in re.findall(pattern, text):  # Number of occurrences in the 'k' line.
    print("Results: %s" % m.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace'))

 print("Method 2\n")
 reg = u"Characters: \"[\u4e00-\u9fff]+.*?"
 pattern = re.compile(reg, re.UNICODE | re.MULTILINE)
 for m in re.findall(pattern, text):  # Number of occurrences in the 'k' line.
    print("Results: %s" % m.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace'))
```

The output is:

```
Method 1

Method 2

Results: Characters: "??
```

The question is how can I make the method 2 result with variables. I didn't find any solution yet and I don't understand why the method 1 doesn't work.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1 does not work because `\u####` doesn't mean anything in the case of an encoded sequence.  Instead, you need the correct sequence in bytes.  If you do this, then method 1 will produce the same results as method 2.  I modified your code as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import re

text = """
saú$_ß$¤×÷asd县阴őasdCharacters: \"县阴 asdsadsasd县阴
"""
text = unicode(text, "utf-8")
print("\nMethod 1\n")
reg = "Characters: \"[\xe4\xb8\x80-\xe9\xbf\xbf]+.*?"
reg = unicode(reg, "utf-8")
pattern = re.compile(reg, re.UNICODE | re.MULTILINE)
for m in re.findall(pattern, text):  # Number of occurrences in the 'k' line.
    print("Results: %s" % m.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace'))

print("\nMethod 2\n")
reg = u"Characters: \"[\u4e00-\u9fff]+.*?"
pattern = re.compile(reg, re.UNICODE | re.MULTILINE)
for m in re.findall(pattern, text):  # Number of occurrences in the 'k' line.
    print("Results: %s" % m.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace'))
```

It produces the following results on my machine:

```
Method 1

Results: Characters: "县阴

Method 2

Results: Characters: "县阴
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another probleme with this. If I want to read this regex from a file and convert to unicode and also read a file and search for this, then this is not work. But if I use the "reg = "Characters: \"[\xe4\xb8\x80-\xe9\xbf\xbf]+.*?" ", then works with opened file.

Comment: Sometimes if you create a file with an editor, it will add a byte marker.  The right answer may be to create the python unicode string, then .encode it into a regular string and write it out to a file.  Then you can later read the string and .decode it back into unicode.